# What is the range of $y$ if $x+y+z=4$ and $xy+yz+xz=5$ for $x, y, z \in\mathbb{R}_+$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization

> What is the range of $y$ if $x+y+z=4$ and $xy+yz+xz=5$ for $x, y, z \in\mathbb{R}_+$

How to explain the following method?

Let $x=z$ then:

$$2x+y=4\quad;\quad 2xy+x^{2}=5$$
$$\implies \left( 4-y\right) y+\left( \dfrac {4-y} {2}\right) ^{2}=5 $$

Simplify: $(3y-2)(y-2)=0$. Then I get $\dfrac {2} {3}\leq y\leq 2$.

But why?

Thanks and sorry for my poor English

Comment: Replacing the values of $z$  with $4-(x+y)$  we get $$x^2+x(y-4)+(y^2-4y+5)=0$$  whose discriminant is $$-(3y-2)(y-2)$$ which needs to be $\ge0$

Comment: It is not obvious that the extremal possible values of $y$ take place when $x=z$. This should be a result of the argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\bf{Another \; Way::}$

Given $x+y+z = 4\Rightarrow x+z=4-y$ and $xy+yz+zx = 5$

Using $$(x+y+z)^2 = x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+yz+zx)\Rightarrow x^2+y^2+z^2 = 6$$

So we get $x^2+z^2 = 6-y^2$

Now Using $\bf{Weighted\; A.M\geq G.M\;,}$ We get

$$\frac{x^2+z^2}{2}\geq \left(\frac{x+z}{2}\right)^2$$

So $$\frac{6-y^2}{2}\geq \left(\frac{4-y}{2}\right)^2\Rightarrow (4-y)^2\leq 12-2y^2$$

So $$16+y^2-8y\leq 12-2y^2\Rightarrow 3y^2-8y+4\leq 0$$

So $$3y^2-6y-2y+4\leq 0\Rightarrow \frac{2}{3}\leq y\leq 2$$