# Obtaining the bound without using only the trivial inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization, maxima-minima

> If $x,y,z$ are 3 real numbers such that $$x+y+z = 4$$ and $$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 6$$ show that each of $x,y,z$ lie in the closed interval $[\frac{2}{3},2]$

I obtained the upper bound, but I am unable to obtain the lower bound.

**My approach**

$x^2 + y^2 + (4-(x+y))^2 = 6$

$\therefore 2x^2 + 2y^2 + 2xy - 8x - 8y = -10 \implies (2-y-x)^2 - 4 -xy = -5 \implies xy -1 \geq 0$ 
$$\therefore \color {blue}{xy \geq 1}$$

similarly we get $yz \geq 1$ and $zx \geq 1$

Now suppose that $z >2 \:\:$ Then $x + y < 2$ and $x^2 + y^2 <2 \implies (x+y)^2 - x^2 - y^2 = \color{red}{2xy < 2}$

Contradiction. A similar argument works for $x$ and $y$. Therefore we have $x,y,z \leq 2$

---

If possible, I'd like a similar argument for the lower bound, i.e, using only the trivial inequality. Thank you.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1623373/what-is-the-range-of-y-if-xyz-4-and-xyyzxz-5-for-x-y-z-in-mathbbr?rq=1) works here don't you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y+z=4-x$ and $(4-x)^2-2yz=6-x^2$, which gives $yz=x^2-4x+5$.

Thus, $(4-x)^2-4(x^2-4x+5)\geq0$, which is $(x-2)(3x-2)\leq0$ and we are done!